# Sending User Name and Password through Mobile Message(SMS) is Possible in Keycloak?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I am using keycloak 4.4.0 Version and I Want to send the User credential to the created users on their Mobile numbers throught Keycloak. Email Message is possible in Keycloak to send Credential but same thing i want to send with Message on mobile.
Please help me on this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You'll need to provide some more context to get help.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

First of all this can be a very insecured model to share credentials over mail/phone. Moreover, that is not possible as Keycloak never knows the password of the users, it only stores the hashed password.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. but i want to know the user credential will be he shared to the users then. How the created users will come to know their password to login. I am using keycloak with spring boot micro services to login on the portal.

Comment: As an admin, while you create a user. On the create users screen once you created the user with email and other details. Go to credentials tab, and select update-password in the Reset Actions  drop-down and click send email button. Once you does that, user would receive an email with a link to set password. By this way, you need not choose password for him and share it over email. You can code this, as keycloak has a REST API for these actions.

Comment: I agree with @raghav, this is the common way to do that. Never share credentials with users, except if you define a temporary password for them. They will then be forced to change it at first login attempt. It is an alternative to the here-above suggestion, also provided by Keycloak console and its API.